# Different home pages based on different conditions?

Tags: 8

I have two pages:

```
/home
/pr
```

Currently, under site configuration, I have /home as the home page. So whenever someone open mysite1.com, it will show the contents at /home. However, multiple domains are parked on this site. I want it in the case of mysite2.com is opened, the /pr page must show, but if mysite1.com is opened, it must show /home like it always does.

At what point would I be able to do this? Where  can I incorporate this logic?

Comment: maybe page_manager module + custom context provider for domain. But I think multisite would be better.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in settings.php and define `$conf['site_frontpage']` from a server variable like `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`. The same logic would allow you to set your `$base_url`(D7) or `$settings['trusted_host_patterns']`(D8) to the correct domain as well.